# How to ask to expect yes/no answer?

Tags: united-states

I wonder if asking something like "Are you responsible for managing the website?" or " will i work with Mr A on this project or someone else" is polite? Especially he works in another department and is a manager whereas I am just a digital executive? And i am not a native speaker. :D

So what i wonder is when you want to have the clarity from someone politely such as yes/no questions but if you keep asking so many questions like that i think it makes you an impolite person.

Comment: Add is it true? To end your question

Comment: If you like, both of your examples can be recast as non yes/no: "Who is responsible for managing the website?" and "With whom will I work on this project?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's impolite. As long as the person you are asking is not busy and is available to answer your questions.

On the event that he is, just (humbly) ask for a particular time where you can ask him away.

it also helps to make sure that he is the right person to ask your particular questions, and there isn't someone much more qualified/suited to assisting your inquiries.

**EDIT, for the comment**

**Scene 1**: Person is busy

You: "Good morning Mr. A! i hope I am not bothering you. If it is alright, may I ask you some questions? I believe you are the best person I can approach you with these"

Mr.A: "Not right now, sorry"

You: "I understand. May I ask you at a later time instead?"

---

Mr.A: "Sure, how about later at 1?"

You: "Alright, thank you very much"

---

Mr.A: "I will be very occupied today"

You: "I understand, another time then. Thank you very much!"

---

**Scene 2**: person can be asked a question

You: "Good morning Mr. A! i hope I am not bothering you. If it is alright, may I ask you some questions? I believe you are the best person I can approach you with these"

Mr.A: "Alright, how can I help?"

You: "Thanks! About website A, I was wondering who manages and maintains the site. who should I talk to?"

Mr.A: (gives answer)

You: "Okay on Project B, on the team composition, will the team compose of me and Mr. Z"

Mr. A: (gives answer)

...basically, you continue from there.

Now that I think about it, the second question sounds like it may have been discussed over a meeting. If you were a part of the meeting, refer to your own notes or on the minutes instead. Should provide you with answers.

Comment: Thanks, however, could you give me some examples like you are going to ask many yes no questions at once, maybe in a more polite way?